# Using all 12 DIMMs on a Dell T610 server

Tags: memory, ddr3, dell-poweredge

I have a Dell T610 server with 2 processors and 6 slots of RAM for each. I only have 1 processor installed.

Can I install RAM in all 12 slots or will it only recognize the RAM if that processor is installed?

Answer (score 1):

The Dell configurator seems to show 96GB with one processor and 192GB with two.  Kingston indicates the  max with no mention of processor but checking with Dell support will likely get the definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the response I got from Dell:

"The memory controller is embedded in the processor with the new DDR3 memory you can only populate the memory channels that have a processor associated with it."

So I guess that's out...